# Why don't multiple subs work together while do individually in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro to do a couple of things. My goal is to import a table then copy it into 3 different sheets in the same file. After all I want to arrange those 4 tables with my subs. Since I have 4 sheets in a file, I need to write a separate sub for each sheet.

At last, I want to assing them to a complete sub called All(). But when I do, my macro goes into infinite loop.

I've tried to run them individually and they worked properly. But I don't know why they don't work when they are run together. Here is my code:

```
Sub Format_1()

    Sheets(1).Range("H2") = "P Axial"

    Dim delete_list(7) As String

    delete_list(0) = "Absolute Distance"
    delete_list(1) = "V2"
    delete_list(2) = "V3"
    delete_list(3) = "T"
    delete_list(4) = "U1 Plastic"
    delete_list(5) = "U2 Plastic"
    delete_list(6) = "U3 Plastic"
    delete_list(7) = "R1 Plastic"

    i = 1

    Do While Sheets(1).Cells(2, i) <> ""

        If IsInArray(Sheets(1).Cells(2, i), delete_list) Then
            Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
            i = i - 1
        End If

        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub

Sub All()

    Call Format_1
    Call Format_2
    Call Format_3
    Call Format_4

End Sub
```

This code will be run for 4 different sheets in the same way. The only change will be Sheets(2), 
Sheets(3), Sheets(4) instead of Sheets(1).

I'd like to know why they don't work together while do individually. Thanks in advance.

P.S.: IsInArray is a function that checks whether a string is seen in an array.

Comment: `Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete` - you need to specify the worksheet.

Comment: Are all the Macro exactly the same excepted sheet name ? if yes I would suggest you to create 1 Macro which loop through all your worksheet and do what you need, you just got to browse all your worksheet..

Comment: Your macro just needs a parameter that must be a worksheet, and then use that parameter in your code. Something like `Sub Format_WK (Byval ThisWK as Worksheet)` and then replace all your `Sheets(1)` by `ThisWK` and call the sub like this `Call Format_WK Sheets(1)` or do a loop to call it once per worksheet.

Comment: Wouldn't use `Sheets(1)` as that's always the first sheet in the workbook which could change if a user moves the sheets around.  Something like `Sheets("Sheet1")` would always point to the tab sheet name, or just `Sheet1` to point to the sheet with that codename (is visible in the VBA Project explorer as the sheet name that isn't in brackets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use sheet references for the macros work, because it will default what's active, but the active one will be whatever you have when you run the macro.

Try this.

```
Sub Format_1()

    Sheets(1).Range("H2") = "P Axial"

    Dim delete_list(7) As String

    delete_list(0) = "Absolute Distance"
    delete_list(1) = "V2"
    delete_list(2) = "V3"
    delete_list(3) = "T"
    delete_list(4) = "U1 Plastic"
    delete_list(5) = "U2 Plastic"
    delete_list(6) = "U3 Plastic"
    delete_list(7) = "R1 Plastic"

    i = 1

    Do While Sheets(1).Cells(2, i) <> ""

        If IsInArray(Sheets(1).Cells(2, i), delete_list) Then
            'I added the Sheet reference, but do this for all of your macros
            Sheets(1).Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete 
            i = i - 1
        End If

        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub

Sub All()

    Call Format_1
    Call Format_2
    Call Format_3
    Call Format_4

End Sub
```